# Write on share variable between projects using VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a Class with Shared variables on a solution that contains 3 projects. I have too a reference to the project that contains shared variables from other 2 projects (we call NoShared Projects).

I can read perfect from NoShared Projects, but the problem it's I can write on shared variables from this projects.

This is the code of the class that contains shared variables.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared Debug As Boolean = False
    Public Shared Username As String = ""
    Public Shared Password As String = ""
End Class
```

If I do this from NoShared Projects:

```
GlobalVariables.Debug = True
```

Nothing happens, the value of `GlobalVariable.Debug` is still `False`.

Any help please?

I'm using different projects because each project require differents permission of execution, like Administrator permission and other normal user permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your running two programs (2 EXE's, or one Web Site one EXE for example) then Shared variables are not global between them. They are only "Shared" globally inside the same application domain (same EXE).

In this case you will need to store the value somewhere else that is global to both projects or store the value in one of the running occurances and provide a way to access it (such as .net remoting, or a web service call) to write to it in only one application space.

One other way to deal with it is to store it in a database where you can pesimistically lock a table that holds the value during updates.